# Ionic3 create a slide introduction issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am following the tutorial below to create a slide introduction:
https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-sliding-introduction-component-in-ionic-2/

But have an error when I set below:

```
this.rootPage = FirstguidePage;
```

the error is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Anyone know how to solve? Thanks a lot~

firstguide.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TabsPage } from '../../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-firstguide',
 templateUrl: 'firstguide.html'
})
export class FirstguidePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  goToHome(){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
  }

}
```

It is the firstguide.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides pager>
    <ion-slide>
      <img src="assets/img/1_zh.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>  
      <img src="assets/img/2_zh.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>  
      <img src="assets/img/3_zh.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>  
      <img src="assets/img/4_zh.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col> 
          <img src="assets/img/5_zh.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <button ion-button style="background-color:#17B97E; color:#FFFFFF;" (click)="goToHome()">{{ 'Firstguide.start' | translate }}
          </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>    
    </ion-slide>

  </ion-slides>

 </ion-content>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code where the slider is initialized (Component and view)?

Comment: Hi sebaferreras, do you means the ts file? I have added it.

Comment: Are you getting the slides using any async method? Or are they just hardcoded in the view?

Comment: They are all images saved in assets/img/.

Comment: Hi, @sebaferreras, I have added the firstguide.html, how can i define the length?

Comment: It should work as it is. Could you please replace all the images, for some dummy text to see if the error is related to that?

Comment: hi,@sebaferreras i have replaced it with <h2>dummy</h2> still have same error.